# Flask Test: preprocess_request(), dispatch_request()

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask

My Environment:

> Python3.7 
>   Flask==1.0.2 
>   pytest==4.3.1

I was looking for a method to retrieve both request object and response object  in pytest function. And then I met across this unit testing snippet.

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/58/

and below is what I did.

```
def test_busking(session, monkeypatch, report=Report()):

    with app.test_request_context('/busking/zones'):
        # call the before funcs
        rv = app.preprocess_request()
        if rv != None:
            response = app.make_response(rv)
        else:
            # do the main dispatch
            rv = app.dispatch_request()
            response = app.make_response(rv)

            # now do the after funcs
            response = app.process_response(response)

        assert flask.request
        assert response
```

It works well In my environment. I was able to get both objects. What my questions are...

- dispatch_request() is called when only `rv is None`. why not when rv is something else?
- process_response() also called when `rv is None` why is that?
- it seams like preprocess_request() calls `before_request_funcs` and rv is the return value of the last `before_request_function`... it looks like rv has nothing to do with dispatching request please but I know It has to be something... tell me what I'm wrong about.

There are still tons of things I don't understand in preprocess_request(), make_response(), dispatch_request(), process_response(). I think rv and process_request() are playing great roles but I'm not sure.  I would be more than greatful if you also explain what is going on background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Flask, so this answer might miss some points, but I think it's enough to help clarify your situation:

- If a `before_request` function returns something else than `None`, it is taken as the view's response, so no more treatment happens, see [preprocess_request's doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=preprocess_request#flask.Flask.preprocess_request)
- `process_response` calls the `after_request` methods, it's called regardless of the response content (AFAIK)
- As per the same doc linked above, I would say that `rv` is the first non-`None` result received from `before_request`, not the last, as as soon as a non-`None` is returned, the processing stops.

At a glance, I would say that this is the order of things:

1. `preprocess_request`: call the `before_request` functions in order
2. As soon as one of them returns something different than `None`, stop calling the remaining ones and jump to (4)
3. `dispatch_request`: call the method associated to the routing rule
4. `make_response`: prepare the `Response` object based on the previous result (here, `rv`)
5. `process_response`: call the `after_request` functions with the `Response` object